# How to increase health when score has reached

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm making a endless runner game. And would like to increase the health/life when a certain score has reached. In a ScoreManager script attached to a ScoreManager I have:

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public int score;
public Text scoreDisplay;

bool one = true;

Player scriptInstance = null;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
    {
        score++;
        Debug.Log(score);
    }
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    GameObject tempObj = GameObject.Find("ghost01");
    scriptInstance = tempObj.GetComponent<Player>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    scoreDisplay.text = score.ToString();

    if (scriptInstance.health <= 0)
    {
        Destroy(this);
    }

    if (score == 75 || score == 76 && one == true)
    {
        scriptInstance.health++;
        one = false;
    }
}
```

I used the following lines to increase the health at a milestone, but have to copy the code endlessly to create multiple milestones.

```
if (score == 75 || score == 76 && one == true)
{
    scriptInstance.health++;
    one = false;
}
```

My question is how to increase health every 75 points, without duplicating the code?

Comment: You might use modulo. Checking `if (score % 75 == 0) { //addHealth}`

Comment: @Willie was also my first thought but still returns true all the time while score stays at `75` ...

Comment: If the milestones are regularly spaced Willie's would be my suggestion otherwise, Id have an array of milestones and when adding score if it equals a milestone etc

Comment: Yes maybe you save weather you added health in a flag. After increasing the score, you reset the flag.

Comment: @Willie if adding an additional flag you can as well simply add a second dedicated counter, though ;)

Comment: @derHugo yes. both solutions are equally fine imo.

Comment: @Willie yes in mine, too. Modulo is often an elegant solution ofcourse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with th `%` operator

```
private bool scoreChanged = false;
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
    {
        score++;
        scoreChanged = true;
        Debug.Log(score);
    }
}

if (score % 75 == 0 && scoreChanged)
{
    scriptInstance.health++;
    scoreChanged = false;
}
```

Comment: was also my first thought but still returns true all the time while score stays at 75 => adds a health per frame

Comment: Quite true, I made some modifications! Quite liked your solution too!

Comment: Jup. Thats what i said in my comment. Would do this exactly this way.

Answer (score 6):

The issue with a modulo like `if(score % 75 == 0)` would be that it returns `true` all the time while `score == 75` .. so it would require an additional `bool` flag anyway.

I would rather simply add a second counter for this!

And not check things repeatedly in `Update` at all but rather the moment you set it:

```
int healthCounter;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
    {
        score++;
        Debug.Log(score);

        // enough to update this when actually changed
        scoreDisplay.text = score.ToString();

        healthCounter++;
        if(healthCounter >= 75)
        {
            scriptInstance.health++;

            // reset this counter
            healthCounter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

the one drawback maybe is that know you have to reset the `healthCounter = 0` wherever you reset the `score = 0` ... but you would have to do the same with any flag solution as well ;)